# Creating dodged graph with 2 column values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am struggling with the following, as I want to create a dodged columns graph (the dataset contains 9 rows, this is an example). I wondered if there is a solution without pivoting longer, and if pivoting longer, what do I need to do?

the data set is

| occ_status_before | value_before | value_after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| worked | 0.3 | 0.35 |
| independent | 0.4 | 0.36 |
| unemployed | 0.2 | 0.9 |

Answer (score 5):

For `ggplot2`, it is better to have data in long format. Try :

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -occ_status_before) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(occ_status_before, value, fill = name) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]